# The Twelve Apostles

Tags: mathematics

You are given an empty square grid. Each cell can be an island with a positive integer $n$ or a bridge connecting islands. The following rules apply:

- Each island with a number $n$ must have exactly $n$ bridges attached to it
- Bridges must be either horizontal or vertical with one or more cells in length
- Bridges cannot intersect, but they can meet at an island
- All islands must be connected into a single component

For example, here is a valid arrangement for islands with numbers 1 to 4:

[image]

Can you find an arrangement for islands with numbers 1 to 12? **Bonus:** what is the smallest rectangle (by area) that can fit such an arrangement?

Comment: If you are wondering, the title is referring to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twelve_Apostles_(Victoria)

Comment: Number of bridges between islands is unlimited? Islands are not allowed to touch? All islands need to be connected?

Comment: ah yes all islands should be connected... will add it in

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Islands can be arranged in one line: putting islands with odd numbers on one end,
>  and islands with even numbers on the other end: numbers in brackets are islands, numbers between dashes are bridges.
>
> ```
>  [ 1] -1- [ 3] -2- [ 5] -3- [ 7] -4- [ 9] -5- [11]
>                                                -6-
>  [ 2] -2- [ 4] -2- [ 6] -4- [ 8] -4- [10] -6- [12]
> ```

> This arrangement needs $3*11=33$ cells.
>  Putting all islands on one long line
>  needs $23$ cells.

> This is the minimum: we need $12$ cells for all the islands, if all islands are to be connected, we need at least $11$ bridges.

Comment: Nice solution. Just realised that the example one follows a similar pattern.

Comment: You can now try another version of this puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

In case not all the islands need to be connected (I have a feeling they might, but the rules do not say this at the time of writing this) a simple solution can be

> Split them in 4 groups of 3 in such a way that the islands in the group are connected, but the groups are not connected.
>  1 - 12 - 11
>  4 - 10 - 6
>  3 - 8 - 5
>  2 - 9 - 7

Comment: To get everything connected: you can add vertical bridges between the islands in columns 2 and 3.

Comment: Ah rigth.... I will try it

Comment: Rules state that all islands "must be connected into a single component".

Comment: @ConnieMnemonic Not at the time the answer was posed, which he states explicitly